# SVN: Keep trunck changes but loose local dev changes

Tags: svn, merge

I have a file on my trunk. The same file exists in my branch. At revision A the files are identical in both branches. Then in revision B I make a local modification in my development branch and commit it. Then through several revisions more trunk changes are integrated and committed into my dev branch. I no longer want the changes I made locally back at revision B but I do definitely need to keep the trunk changes made since then. Neither set is all that trivial.

So I reverted my development branch file back to rev A with a backward merge. Then I thought I could merge mack in from trunk to pick up all changes since that revision to achieve what I wanted... But it doesn't detect any changes.

Anyone know how I can accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: *I no longer want the changes I made locally* - in that case you can do `svn revert PATH` (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html).   
*So I reverted my development branch file back to rev A with a backward merge* - did you `commit` that? If not, just discard merge from local copy and do `svn revert PATH`.
*But it doesn't detect any changes.* - Because `svn:mergeinfo` property indicates that changeset is already merged (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo)

Comment: if the local changes happened and were committed before a merge from tunk to dev, which was then also committed, can I still do a revert like that? Updating question to make that more clear

Comment: Yes, you can do it by "cherrypick" your revision and "reverse merging": `svn merge -c -REV_NO` - *An extremely common use for svn merge is to roll back a change that has already been committed.* (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo)

Comment: Okay, so in the question I said that I did a reverse merge. This works in my dev branch. But then I want the mainline changes that have occurred since the revision I merged back to and doing a merge from tunk to mainline isn't getting this done...

Comment: You have started with rev A. Then in rev B, you have changed your file on branch. Then revisions C and D were merged from trunk and commited to branch in revisions E and F. Than you have reverted to rev A and commited that on branch (which is now rev G). You need to: first revert G (which will get back your merge from trunk to branch) and then revert B (which will get your file to state in rev A): `cd path-to-branch`,`svn merge -c -G` and `svn merge -c -B`. If your branch working copy looks fine after this, `commit` and you are done.

Comment: awesome, thanks! I will give that a try in just a bit

Comment: didn't work on my branche but I created a little test branch with some dummy files to emulte this and it worked perfectly so in principle it worked... so thank you for your help. I just need to figure out what I've done on my real branch. If you wanna post as an answer I will upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments:

You have started with rev A. Then in rev B, you have changed your file on branch. Then revisions C and D were merged from trunk and commited to branch in revisions E and F. Than you have reverted to rev A and commited that on branch (which is now rev G).

You need to:

- first revert G (which will get back your merge from trunk to branch)
- and then revert B (which will get your file to state in rev A): `cd path-to-branch`, `svn merge -c -G` and `svn merge -c -B`.

If your branch working copy looks fine after this, `commit` and you are done.